# wxWidgets Issue: wxDummyConsoleApp::OnRun() unreachable code

Tags: c++, user-interface, dll, wxwidgets

I am looking at this example [EXAMPLE](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/overview_helloworld.html). I copy past after linking the dlls and all. I get this error after running it:

`wxDummyConsoleApp::OnRun() unreachable code` thrown in `wxWidgets/common/init.cpp`[image].

Could you please help me?

I am using: Visual Studio 2022 (v143)

Thank you!

Comment: Don't post images of code or errors - post *text* directly in the question. Same goes for linking to code; don't do it - post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) directly *in* your question, as *text*.

Comment: There is no way someone who is not experienced in wxWidgets will answer this question, so please ignore. This is a known problem as mentioned [here](https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?t=6950). I am talking to people who had this issue before and this might help others in the future if I get an answer.

Answer (score -1):

I was linking with 2 copies of wxWidgets -- one of which remains uninitialized. This is a problem with your build setting. In my case I was doing this in my prmeake:

```
links
    {
        "wxbase33ud.lib",
        "wxregexud.lib",
        "comdlg32.lib",
        "advapi32.lib",
        "msvcprtd.lib",
        "oleaut32.lib",
        "wxexpatd.lib",
        "wxzlibd.lib",
        "wxtiffd.lib", 
        "shell32.lib",
        "wxjpegd.lib", 
        "LIBCMT.lib",
        "rpcrt4.lib",
        "user32.lib",
        "wxpngd.lib",
        "gdi32.lib",
        "ole32.lib",
        "wxpng.lib",    
    }
```

I deleted all this and it works fine.